# Cycles render using GPU gives CUDA error

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

Running Blender 2.77a on LXDE - can't use GPU for cycles render. Error is 'CUDA error at cuModuleLoad: Invalid kernel image'.

Am using kernel: 3.13.0-92-generic.
Version: Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

Works perfectly using Blender 2.76 or 2.76b

Comment: If it's working on previous versions it is probably a bug.  To report please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports

Comment: Are you on a 32bits version of Blender ? If yes have a look here https://blender.org/manual/fr/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#cuda-error-invalid-kernel-image.